# Can't convert the Ruler/Protractor into any Geometry type

Tags: grease-pencil

So I clicked on "Ruler/Protractor" button, drew a 3-meter line, and tried to convert it into a curve or poly but no joy. The options are inactive before you go into Ruler mode, and when you actually go into the Ruler mode and draw the actual line, the mouse cursor changes into a crosshair shape and does not allow you to click on any button in the UI. And when I hit enter, I'm out of Ruler mode, the line disappears, and the "Convert to Geometry" 3 drop-down menu options are inactive again.

Is that a bug in Blender or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly as you said. The menu was active indeed, but it gave an error:
"Current Grease Pencil strokes have no valid timing data, most timing options will be hidden!" The exclamation mark was in the actual line

Comment: That isn't an error, it's a notification that's Grease Pencil layer doesn't have any data related to movements of the pencil when drawing it (as it's drawn procedurally by Blender itself it won't have any). Timing is related to cases when you drew a sketch with GP with a pen of graphic tablet and want to save data about how fast was your hand moving when drawing it etc for further use. So it looks like error but you can just skip that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Once drawn [ruler](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/ruler_protractor.html#ruler-protractor) gets saved into a Grease Pencil layer specifically created for it. However this layer will be hidden so that's why it seems that ruler disappears. With it visible converting a ruler into geometry is the same as for [converting GP strokes into curves](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/grease_pencil/convert_to_geometry.html).

After hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to store the ruler, open Properties shelf with <kbd>N</kbd>, scroll it to the *Grease Pencil layers* rollout and enable visibility for the layer with the ruler/-s (it should be called something like "RulerData3D"). Make sure to select the layer itself. Then options in the Toolshelf > Grease Pencil > *Convert to Geometry* will become active.

[image]

Note that as *Store* ruler is used after drawning it to pass it to Grease Pencil and then - to geometry, if you press Ruler/Protractor to draw another one, the one you drew before will be still there (it is saved as ruler regardless).